# What do I do with things my Pokemon pick up?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

Is there any non-monetary use for the Lone Earrings (Pretty Wings, Beach Glass, etc.) that my Eevee has been giving me or am I just supposed to sell them to buy fancy hats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no use for the items gifted by your Pokemon, with the exception of the Heart Scale, except to sell them for money at shops.

A full list of items your partner Pokemon can gift to you can be found in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/341233/88253).

Comment: That list includes Heart Scale, which can be used at Indigo Plateau to relearn a previous forgotten move.

Comment: @Kruga Thanks for clarifying.  Haven't made it that far yet, but I've updated my answer to include this correction.